# Quicksort.js uncaught typeError cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, html, quicksort

I've been trying to figure out why I keep getting "uncaught typeerror cannot read property of null" on line 4 of my Javascript. First question on this site, maybe someone here can help!

```
function sort() {

var array = document.getElementById(array);
    array.sort(function (left, right)
    {
        return left-right;
    });
    console.log(array);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title> quickSort.html </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="materialize.css"/>
</head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="QuickSort.js"></script>
<body>

    <center> <h1 class="animated fadeIn" id="title"> quickSort.js </h1> </center>

        <center> <input id="array" type="text" placeholder=" enter a set of numbers or words"></input> </center>

            <center> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="sort()">sort</a> </center>


</body>
```

Comment: and when you get that working,,,,you can not sort a DOM node

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(array)
```

You have no variable named `array`.  That's not going to work.
You probably want a string literal.